# CSS Layout issues

Tags: css

I have inherited a code-base. I need to add a div to a webpage that:

- Is centered,
- All of the content is stacked horizontally (not vertically)

Currently, I have

```
<div style="background-color:silver; padding:8px; text-align:center;">
    <input type='text' value='birth date'/>

    <select>
        <option>Male</option>
        <option>Female</option>
    </select>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Is New?" />
</div>
```

When this content is rendered, the silver box is the width of the entire screen. But, I just want it to be the width of the content, with the 8px padding between the edges and the controls. I then want the div centered. What am i doing wrong?

thank you!

Comment: which browser are you viewing it it?

Answer (score 0):

set a width value for your div and put the margin auto, like this:

```
<div style="background-color:silver; margin: auto; width: 250px; padding: 8px;">
```

Edit:

You could do it this way then:

```
<div style="text-align:center;padding:8px;">
    <span style="background:silver;padding:8px;">
        <input type='text' value='birth date'/>
        <select>
            <option>Male</option>
            <option>Female</option>
        </select>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Is New?" />   
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: But, I'm not sure how wide the content of the div will be. Is there a way to make it dynamic?

Comment: This works but unfortunately it is brittle: Consider this [working version](http://jsfiddle.net/2RzuF/1/) (ok in chrome) vs this [broken version](http://jsfiddle.net/2RzuF/2/). The working one might not even be cross-browser (or cross-OS) depending on the fonts used.